# Build a json in php from POST data

Tags: php, json

I need to update a json list of object via url post data. For example, with url:

```
http://myweb.com/index.php?name=Peter&surname=Brown
```

in php, using get method:

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$surname = $_GET["surname"];
$json = array();

        $json["nombre"] = $name;
        $json["lat"] = $lat;
        $data[] = $json;

$json_end= json_encode($data);
```

and json_end efectively is done like I want:

```
[{"name":"Peter","surname":"Brown"}]
```

My question is about how I can do it incrementing the json, in order to build an array like:

```
[{"name":"Peter","surname":"Brown"}]
[{"name":"newname","surname":"newsurname"}]
// and so on
```

each time user  use the url with new parameters.

Do I need to write to a file, or to database? Any tips will be apreciated.

The idea is to be able that  any user can add some dat using url. I tried to store the json to a fiel but the storing is durable only along the current session.

Comment: You're gonna need to save the old parameters somewhere.  Each time you load the URL, PHP is loaded anew, with no memory of the last time (except for `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`).  A database sounds good here.

Comment: Yes, you need to store the old data in file/db/session because each time the user submit the parameters through the url the entire page will be re-generated and your variables will be inicialized

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do?  Do you want to permanently save these names?  Temporarily?  What are they being used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
/* This needs to be at the top of your file, without ANYTHING above it */
session_start();

/* ... */

if(!array_key_exists('entries', $_SESSION))
{
    $_SESSION['entries'] = array();
}

$_SESSION['entries'][] = array("name" => $_GET["name"], "surname" => $_GET["surname"]);

$json_string = json_encode($_SESSION['entries']);
```

This would produce a single JSON.  However I don't know whether you meant to or not, but your output is a series of separate JSONs.  You could do this by replacing the last line above with:

```
$json_string = '';
foreach($_SESSION['entries'] as $entry){ 
    $json_string.= json_encode($entry) . "\n";
}
```

You would also probably want a way to reset/empty the array.  In which case I'd change the if test from:

```
if(!array_key_exists('entries', $_SESSION))
```

to:

```
if(!array_key_exists('entries', $_SESSION) || array_key_exists('reset', $_GET))
```

Which you could use by visiting

```
http://myweb.com/index.php?reset
```

---

***Edit:*** If somewhere you add the following code:

```
foreach($_SESSION['entries'] as $id=>$entry){ 
    printf("%2d: %s\n", $id, json_encode($entry));
}
```

You'll get a list of the json elements enumerated by their respective keys.  For example, it might look like:

```
 0: "[{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"surname\":\"Brown\"}]"
 1: "[{\"name\":\"newname\",\"surname\":\"newsurname\"}]"
 2: "[{\"name\":\"George\",\"surname\":\"Washington\"}]"
 3: "[{\"name\":\"John\",\"surname\":\"Adams\"}]"
```

If you then add the following code:

```
if(array_key_exists('del', $_GET) && is_numeric($_GET['del']))
{
    $key = (int)$_GET['del'];
    if(array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION['entries']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['entries'][$key]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf('<strong>ERROR: $_GET['del'] = %d but $_SESSION['entries'][%d] doesn't exist.</strong>', $key, $key);
    }
}
```

you'll be able to delete individual json entries by specifying id as the `del` GET parameter.

For example,

```
http://myweb.com/index.php?del=2
```

would delete the entry corresponding to `'[{"name":"George","surname":"Washington"}]';`

And the remaining entries would be:

```
 0: "[{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"surname\":\"Brown\"}]"
 1: "[{\"name\":\"newname\",\"surname\":\"newsurname\"}]"
 3: "[{\"name\":\"John\",\"surname\":\"Adams\"}]"
 4: "[{\"name\":\"Thomas\",\"surname\":\"Jefferson\"}]"
```

Comment: It was incredible efective for me. and the reset command is very useful. Is it possible to delete a specific entry to? anyway Thanks a lot for the so fast answer!

Comment: Sure, how would you want to refer to the entry though?  In other words, how would you want to do that?

Comment: When I obtein one single json like: 
{"persons": [{"name":"Peter","surname":"Brown"},{"name":"Peter2","surname":"newsurname1"},
{"name":"Peter3","surname":"Brown"},{"name":"Peter4","surname":"newsurname"}]
}
is possible to erase only one?

Comment: Yes, its certainly possible, but I'm asking you how you would want to do that?  By json number, by name, etc.

Comment: for example, by an id: {"id"="0" ,"name":"Peter0","surname":"newsurname10"},{"id"="1" ,"name":"Peter1","surname":"newsurname1"}, ....

Comment: @doxsi, I updated the post, try it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, just now I realize that the json incremet well but ONLY in the current session, inclusive if I use write to a  file. There is a way to do that? the incremnt coulf work with someone use the URL...

Comment: @doxsi, I see you unchecked this as the correct answer, presumably because I didn't respond to your week-later follow up question fast enough.  Considering the question didn't change, I'm a bit confused about how the answer suddenly became incorrect.  In any case, if you have additional questions that fall outside the scope of your original question, the best way would be to create a new question and reference this one.  You'll get many more eyes that way.

Comment: Sorry, how I said in prevouse comment, I realize that your ask is corret but not completely for me. The json is acualize but onlyy along a session, but i need a permante json . Anyway, yoe was brillant, perharps it is better  create a new question abouyt it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Just make a nested array of users:

```
$data = array (
    0 => array("name"=>"Peter","surname"=>"Brown"),
    1 => array("name"=>"newname","surname"=>"newsurname")
);

echo json_encode($data);

// [{"name":"Peter","surname":"Brown"},{"name":"newname","surname":"newsurname"}]
```

Comment: The question here seems to be how to save/retrieve the other users.  Since only one user is sent via `GET`.  So a nested array is a good idea, but asked where he should save this, so it gets loaded each time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easiest to store the data in a session, something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['json'][] = $_GET;
    }

    echo json_encode($_SESSION['json']);
?>
```

Edit: You may want to filter the $_GET array before storing it in the session so that you don't store values that aren't meant to be stored.

Edit: Of course, if you want to save this data for more than one session you would need to use files or a database (or perhaps a cookie). It all depends on what you want to do with the information.

Comment: To use sessions you always need to run `session_start()` before any output. I've updated the answer.