# POST data to permanent json file using PHP

Tags: php, json

using a url, my idea is that any user can post data. For example via

http://myweb.com/index.php?name=Peter&surname=Brown

Using the "jedwards" answer, present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210779/build-a-json-in-php-from-post-data/11210965#comment14900549_11210965), I am able to create a json  and save it to a file.

```
<?
/* This needs to be at the top of your file, without ANYTHING above it */
session_start();

/* ... */

if(!array_key_exists('entries', $_SESSION))
{
    $_SESSION['entries'] = array();
}

$_SESSION['entries'][] = array("name" => $_GET["name"], "surname" => $_GET["surname"]);

$json_string = json_encode($_SESSION['entries']);
```

My problem is that this is not permanent amongst different session or user. It works only on the same session. On different session the json built start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `GET` requests to change the state of the server. `GET` is only supposed to read (or.. um.. **GET**) data from the server.

In order to change data, use `POST`. It's more fitted, slightly more secure, and is great when transferring larger amounts of data.

Now, for the problem at hand. For a more permenant solution, the best option is to enforce user registration, and save the required data on a database, with a reference to the user's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because sessions, as the name imply, are only temporary (and *sort of* local). When the browser is closed it's gone. Depending on what your demands are you'll have to choose between using a database or textfiles on the server.

Cookies or sessions is not made for this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for a rudimentary solution, see below. If not, use a database as suggested in the other answers.

```
<?
/* This needs to be at the top of your file, without ANYTHING above it */
session_start();

/* ... */

$file = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/entries.json';
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$entries = (!empty($data)) ? json_decode($data) : array();

$entries[] = array("name" => $_GET["name"], "surname" => $_GET["surname"]);

file_put_contents($file,json_encode($entries),FILE_APPEND);
```